# Prove that ($\Sigma \cup \{ \alpha \}) \vDash \beta$ if and only if $\Sigma \vDash (\alpha \to \beta)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Prove that ($\Sigma \cup \{ \alpha \}) \vDash \beta$ if and only if $\Sigma \vDash (\alpha \to \beta)$

This question is quite simple, but I don't know how to express my proof formally.

I assume that there is an assignment $v$ satisfying every elenment in $\Sigma$, which also satisfies $\alpha \to \beta$, such that for any time that $\alpha$ is true, $\beta$ can't be false.

And if an assignment that satisfies $\Sigma$, and when it satisfies $\alpha$, the $\beta$ can be true.

Sorry, my description is quite unclear.

Comment: Where is your proof?

Comment: To clarify this statement ^ a bit: your sentence suggests you have a proof idea which you cannot formalize— it would be helpful if you posted that idea in the question, so that people can write you a more useful answer.

Comment: In addition, could you please place brackets where appropriate? There is no standard order of operations in logic, so the question is a bit ambiguous at the moment.

Comment: 'delegation'?  Never seen that term ... I know this as 'valuation'

Comment: Assume there is a model in which $\Sigma$ is true and $\alpha\to\beta$ is false. This is a model in which $\Sigma$, $\alpha$ and $\neg\beta$ are true.

That means that there is a model in which $(\Sigma\cup\{\alpha\})$ is true and $\beta$ is false. But that contradicts the assumption.

Comment: @Olivia Will not Σ∪{α} be an object as opposed to a statement, and not have a truth value? Also, if Σ∪{α}  does have a truth value, I don't think it contradicts the assumption. In both cases the antecedent is true and the consequent false. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @user400188 The assumption is that $\beta$ is a consequence of $(\Sigma\cup\{\alpha\})$. That means that for every model in which $\Sigma\cup\{\alpha\}$ is true $\beta$ must also be true. Finding one in which the first is true and the second false is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Sigma \cup \{ \alpha \} \vDash \beta$ iff (definition $\Sigma \vDash \varphi$)

for all interpretations $I$: If $I\vDash \Sigma \cup \{ \alpha \}$ then $I\vDash \beta$ iff (definition $I \vDash \Sigma$)

for all interpretations $I$: If $I\vDash \varphi$ for all $\varphi \in \Sigma \cup \{ \alpha \}$ then $I\vDash \beta$ iff (pure logic)

for all interpretations $I$: If $I\vDash \varphi$ for all $\varphi \in \Sigma$ then if $I \vDash \alpha$ then $I\vDash \beta$ iff (semantics $\rightarrow$)

for all interpretations $I$: If $I\vDash \varphi$ for all $\varphi \in \Sigma$ then $I \vDash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$ iff (definition $I \vDash \Sigma$)

for all interpretations $I$: If $I\vDash \Sigma$ then if $I \vDash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$ iff (definition $\Sigma \vDash \varphi$)

$\Sigma \vDash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$

Answer (score 0):

If Σ⊨(α→β), and (Σ∪{α}) holds, then both Σ and α hold (a set is only true if every member of the set holds true).  Since Σ holds, we can infer that (α→β) holds.  Since α holds also, by semantic detachment β holds.

If (Σ∪{α})⊨β and Σ holds, either α holds or α is false.  If α holds, then β follows by the first assumption also.  Since (β→(α→β)) is a logical law, (α→β) follows by detachment.  Now, ($\lnot$α→(α→β)) is a logical law also.  So, if α is false is, then $\lnot$α is true.  Thus, by semantic detachment (α→β) follows.  Both cases for α have now gotten covered.  Thus, under the hypothesis of (Σ∪{α})⊨β and Σ holding, (α→β) holds.

By the above two paragraphs, (Σ∪{α})⊨β if and only if Σ⊨(α→β).